# Parameter Binding (string to int) in Web API Core 3.1

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-3.1, webapi

I have two GET methods in my controller.

```
[HttpGet("{userId:int}", Name= nameof(GetUserById))]
GetUserById
```

and

```
[HttpGet("{name:alpha}", Name=nameof(GetUserByName))]
GetUserByName
```

Unfortunately, there exists a user with the name "007". When I call http://api/Users/007, the first method is being called since the system treats it as an integer with value 7.

Any possible ways to direct the request to the second method, without making it a query parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I call http://api/Users/007, the first method is being called since the system treats it as an integer with value 7.

Specified URL doesn't match the `GetUserByName` route because of route constraint. `alpha` constraint accepts only letters, not numbers. You have to change your constraint to less restrictive that accepts numbers in parameter or remove constraints at all. See: [Route constraint reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference)

The most reliable way to differentiate these two is to use different templates:

```
[HttpGet("{userId:int}", Name= nameof(GetUserById))] // leave it as is
GetUserById

<...>
[HttpGet("name/{name}", Name=nameof(GetUserByName))] // add segment to route
GetUserByName
```

ASP.NET router has no knowledge that "007" should be trated as string just because there is such user. You should be more specific in your intention and if parameter value can match multiple endpoints, make different endpoint routes. Thus, router will route request to the right action, instead of trying to find best match which may not be your best match.